# Python Multipart E-Mail

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to build a python mailserver that rewrites certain URLs (given in a text file).
Plaintext messages work without problems, but multipart (HTML) E-Mails are a bit of concern to me. I can't find a proper way to rebuild the message after modifying the body and replace functions do not exist for email in python.

What I have currently (for plaintext messages, currently without replacement):

```py
if(not msg.is_multipart()):
    for part in msg.walk():
        parttype = part.get_content_type()
        partmaintype = parttype.split("/")[0]
        partsubtype = parttype.split("/")[1]
        parttype=partmaintype + "/" + partsubtype
        bodypart = part.get_body(('plain','html'))
        #bodypart = bodypart.get_content().encode()
        bodypart = bodypart.get_content()
        print(bodypart)
        newmsg.set_content(bodypart)
        #print(newmsg)
        newdata = bytes(newmsg)
```

The `_structure(msg)` function is in knowledge to me, but I cannot find a way to preserve this message structure (to rebuild the email with a new message object). I also know about the msg.walk() function, but when used with multipart message contents, the subcontents occur twice.

Thanks a lot in advance!